# Why was the "Warm Welcome" Hat changed?

Tags: support

For this year's Holiday Winter bash, I had earned the Warm Welcome hat. It was a traditional-looking Russian style hat, with a red and yellow star on its front. I liked it because it referenced the Soviet Union, which I unshamefully admit to have taken a liking to. But This morning, I came to check my inbox and noticed something different. The Star was replaced with a heart. I was confused and wanted to ask why my favourite hat has been changed.

Comment: I have no clue. We moderators have no saying in the hat thing...

Comment: You can always, [make your own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srffn.png?s=328&g=1), of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Warm Welcome" hat was changed as per [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340512/461068) on the main SE Meta. Essentially, it was changed *because* it referenced the Soviet Union - users from former Soviet nations objected to the use of a symbol that, to them, represented an oppressive, totalitarian regime. While not *everyone* agreed it was offensive, enough people *did* agree that the SE staff decided to change the design.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. It did seem *odd* to me that it was the USSR logo. Not exactly offensive but "warm" and "USSR" aren't exactly linked in my mind. *Especially* when you add in "welcome" to the phrase. At best, I can picture the infamously cold, cold, *cold* Russian winters. At worse, I picture Siberia - the notoriously cold place where people were also notoriously exiled to. It's literally the opposite of "warm" and "welcoming" in *both* the literal and figurative sense of each word. A simple ushanka-hat with no logo would have been enough convey a warmer more welcoming image.